# Cloudgraph service throws Number format exception under high load conditions

Tags: java, maven

Cloudgraph service throws Number format exception under high load conditions.

We randomly see the following exception under high load.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:431)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
at java.text.DigitList.getLong(DigitList.java:177)
at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1297)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1589)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1311)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
at org.plasma.sdo.helper.DataConverter.fromString(DataConverter.java:1768)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was fixed in plasma 1.2.0 and is up on Maven Central. See [Plasma Release 1.2.0](https://github.com/terrameta/plasma/releases/tag/v.1.2.0) for details. I assume you are using cloudgraph.hbase or cloudgraph.rdb. If so you can just upgrade to CloudGraph 0.6.0 beta which depends on plasma 1.2.0. Note that some mapreduce classes under cloudgraph.hbase were promoted (moved up) in case you are using these. So then your pom.xml looks something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudgraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudgraph-hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

--regards;